# Jenkins + Sonarqube. How to fail the pipeline in case Sonarqube detects some syntax error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We're using Sonarqube in some of our Jenkins pipelins. At this moment, we're only inspecting the reports generated by Sonarqube, to try to improve our code quality, but the quality gate is not set to mark as failed the pipeline step, in case the quality gate is not passed.

However, we would like that Sonarqube marks the pipeline step as failed in Jenkins, in case some syntax error is found within code.

As an example, we found the following in the console output in some of our recent deployments from one of our pipelines:

```
...
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
ERROR: Failed to parse file [file:///home/jenkins/workspace/Project_Name/server/app.js] at line 231: Unexpected token )
INFO: Sensor ESLint-based SonarJS [javascript] (done) | time=1683ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=2ms
...
```

In this case, the developer wrote an unneeded closing parenthesis. Sonarqube detected it, but the step was not marked as failed, and the pipeline continued and, as you may guess, the deployed code didn't work.

I've been looking in the documentation, but I couldn't find how to configure the quality gate, so that Sonarqube marks it as failed **ONLY** in case some syntax error is found.

Is it possible? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable pipeline will compile code and run unit tests before even attempting to scan the code with SonarQube. If any of those steps before the SonarQube scan fail, it won't even attempt the SonarQube scan.